# How do I resize my video? in proportion (python)

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library, moviepy

*I am sorry for my poor English. It's a translator.

I used Python moviepy to resize it, but the pixels are broken. I want to make the video 9:16 ratio while maintaining the original image quality. (So that there are black frames on both sides)

```
from moviepy.editor import *
c = VideoFileClip('test.mp4')
f = c.resize(newsize=(1080,1920))
f.write_videofile('aa.mp4')
```

This code causes pixels to collapse.

Let me show you an example picture.

[Original Video Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FlDM.jpg)

[The video I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULZrP.png)

[Pictures that come out using movie resize (other example pictures, pixels collapse and proportions collapse) Pictures that I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hzMt.jpg)

It doesn't have to be moviepy, so I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to use Python. (PIL? opencv?)

Thank you so much. Have a nice day

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html). If you pass width and height with another aspect ratio than the original clip then the output will be distorted, of course.

Comment: if you really need to use that aspect ratio, you may crop the video othervise resize will break the aspect ratio. After cropping you can resize to the 1080,1920 accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FFmpeg, you need to scale then pad your frames. You can achieve this by running your frames through `scale` then `pad` filters. You can find the filter documentation [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).

Assuming your input is taller than 16:9. The command you need is:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf 
    scale=-1:1080,pad=w=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2 aa.mp4
```

Assuming you have `ffmpeg` binary on the system path, you can run this command from Python by

```py
import subprocess as sp

cmd = ['ffmpeg','-i','test.mp4','-vf','scale=-1:1080,pad=w=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2','aa.mp4']
sp.run(cmd)
```

If you want something simpler, you can try my [`ffmpegio` package](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) which you can install by

```
pip ffmpegio-core
```

then in Python

```py
import ffmpegio

ffmpegio.transcode('test.mp4','aa.mp4',vf='scale=-1:1080,pad=w=1920:x=(ow-iw)/2')
```

If you need higher quality mp4, you can add `crf=xx` argument. (The wiki says crf ~18 yields no loss of perceptual quality.)

You can add any ffmpeg output/global options as an argument. If you need to add an input argument, modify the input name by appending `_in`. For example, say to get a clip from at 10 s to 20 s, you can add `ss_in=10, to_in=20`.

Comment: thx , but Is there a way if it's less than 16:9?